# blender как убрать тень от объекта

Tags: blender

Ситуация такая, есть текст, нужно убрать тени от него. При этом, нужно убрать только тени которые он отбрасывает, а которые на нем самом оставить. Вот так выглядит в blender'е:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот так в рендере:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е.  вот эти тени на тексте оставить, а на стене убрать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В настройках материала нужно указать **Shadow mode** - **None**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ой, на картинке промахнулся, пункт ниже, ну вы наверное уже и так поняли

Comment: В Blender 3.0 этот пункт находится в *Material Properties -> Viewport Display -> Settings*